# Juniper EX3300 and Q-in-Q

Tags: vlan, juniper, juniper-ex, qinq, dot1q

I have a Juniper EX3300 switch that has a 10Gbps connection to our upstream provider.

Our upstream provider (lets call them Provider A) passes us various connections on tagged VLANs over this single connection. Transit and interconnect etc.

We now have a 3rd party provider (Provider B) who has a pop in another data center that we need to pull into our network. It was agreed that Provider A would run a L2 interconnect to their pop and then pass their traffic tagged down our 10Gb trunk. This was all fine until the requirement has changed.

Provider B now needs to send us their customer traffic tagged on various VLANs. This means that we need to somehow accept VLANs in VLANs (Q-in-Q).

It looks to me like the EX3300 can only use the dot1q-tunneling options within the vlans stanza and you can't mix and match VLANs using dot1q-tunneling with VLANs that aren't.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I might be able to run both on my trunk port?

**EDIT1**

ProviderB is passing us Customer1's traffic tagged on VLAN 1201. ProviderA is passing us all of ProviderB's traffic tagged on VLAN 1755

```
ProviderB-Customer1 {
    vlan-id 1755;
    interface {
        xe-0/1/0.0;
    }
    dot1q-tunneling {
        customer-vlans 1201;
    }
}
```

However I can't commit this config mixing dot1q-tunneling with normal VLANs

```
error: Trunk interface <ae0.0> can not be memeber of both dot1q-tunneling enabled vlan <ProviderA-Customer1>, and a non dot1q-tunneled vlan <ProviderA-Transit> when dot1q-tunneling ethernet-type is not <0x8100>
error: configuration check-out failed
```

**EDIT2**
I have just found a post on the [Juniper forums](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/Ethernet-Switching/QinQ-VLAN-transport-Issue-over-Etherchannel/td-p/222647) that contains the following snippet

> When enabling dot1q tunneling, the inner ether-type VLAN tag (C-TAG)
>   uses the TPID value of 0x8100 while the outer ether-type VLAN tag
>   (S-VLAN) uses the TPID value of 0x88A8. By default, a standard trunk
>   interface understands the 0x8100 format and will not understand how to
>   process a VLAN tag with the TPID value of 0x88A8. Because of this
>   behavior, you must EITHER enable dot1q tunneling on all trunk
>   interfaces that will be passing the S-VLAN tag OR you can set the
>   dot1q tunneling VLAN tags to use the TPID value of 0x8100 by manually
>   defining the dot1q tunneling ether-type value under the
>
> [edit ethernet-switching-options]
>   set dot1q-tunneling ether-type 0x8100.
>
> One or the other.

I have tried this and I can now commit my config with both normal VLANs and dot1q enabled VLANs on the same port. Hopefully this will work as expected!